# Sending data from mobile client to java server every second

Tags: java, json, html, mobile, client-server

This is the situation:

I have a smartphone client (html5 webApp) that generates about 3-6 float numbers.I need to send these numbers to a java server, which do some operations and returns only an integer number. The problem here is that the client needs sending the numbers every second, or at least every five seconds.

I was wondering if use JSON could be a good solution, but I am not sure about what is the best approach (I guess that some kind of web service or similar)

I need help finding the best way to implement this. Of course the aim is get the lightest and fastest way.

Thanks to all!

(Sorry if the post is not constructive. Feel free to delete it.)

Comment: The fast way is to use Html5 Websockets. As that would allow you to communicate by opening a socket between your app and java server. It is lightweight than simple http get,post etc. Check out these links http://www.pubnub.com/blog/what-are-websockets/ WebSockets vs RestService explained http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/websockets-rest and u can easily use json to exchange your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast way is to use `Html5 Websockets`. As that would allow you to communicate by opening a `socket between your app and java server`. It is `lightweight` than simple http get,post etc i.e `Rest Web Service`. Check out these links

[What Are Websockets](http://www.pubnub.com/blog/what-are-websockets/)

WebSockets vs RestService explained

[WebSockets Vs RestService](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/websockets-rest)

and u can easily use json to exchange your data. Json and Xml are a standard so no worries.

Here you can easily see that how by using Websockets u are able to actually reduce the message overhead which in turn provides scalability and efficiency.

[Websockets VS Rest Comparison](http://blog.arungupta.me/2014/02/rest-vs-websocket-comparison-benchmarks/)

And here is a nice tutorial explaining how to implement WebSockets in Java

[Java Websockets Tutorial](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client)

Comment: @DarioBD I am glad it helped :) Dont forget to upvote and accept this as an answer :)

Comment: Answer accepted, sorry but cannot vote up cause I´m new and I dont have reputation :( (need 15)

Answer (score 0):

Use Json As it is very light weight and for sending and recieving use AJAX.

Or You can also use websocket with JSON.